# Siddhi (as a libary) many queries for the Same Stream

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, siddhi

(I'm jumping from Esper to Siddhi)

I'm trying to deploy several queries in the same stream. The example here https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Using+Siddhi+as+a+Library shows how to deploy a query in a stream, altogether in one ExecutionPlan. So what if I want to add a query to the same execution plan, o same stream?

I'm interest to do this grammatically, Java code.

**UPDATE**

I want to add queries in an existing execution plan. This means while streams are arriving, and not before.
Using an example posted as answer:

```
SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();

String executionPlan = "" +
                       "@Plan:name('demo') " +
                       "" +
                       "define stream cseEventStream (symbol string, price float, volume long);" +
                       "" +
                       "from cseEventStream[symbol==\"WSO2\"] " +
                       "insert into wso2Stream;" +
                       "" +
                       "from cseEventStream[symbol==\"ABC\"] " +
                       "insert into abcStream;";

ExecutionPlanRuntime executionPlanRuntime = siddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(executionPlan);

StreamCallback streamCallback = new StreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void receive(Event[] events) {
        EventPrinter.print(events);
    }
};

executionPlanRuntime.addCallback("wso2Stream", streamCallback);
//Similarly, we can add another call back for abcStream

streamCallback.startProcessing();

InputHandler inputHandler = executionPlanRuntime.getInputHandler("cseEventStream");

executionPlanRuntime.start();
// HERE: ADD new query <---------------------------------------------
inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"WSO2", 700f, 100l});
inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"ABC", 60.5f, 200l});
inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"WSO2", 60.5f, 200l});

streamCallback.stopProcessing();
executionPlanRuntime.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following sample adds multiple Queries, for same Stream (`cseEventStream`), within the same Execution Plan.

```
SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();

String executionPlan = "" +
                       "@Plan:name('demo') " +
                       "" +
                       "define stream cseEventStream (symbol string, price float, volume long);" +
                       "" +
                       "from cseEventStream[symbol==\"WSO2\"] " +
                       "insert into wso2Stream;" +
                       "" +
                       "from cseEventStream[symbol==\"ABC\"] " +
                       "insert into abcStream;";

ExecutionPlanRuntime executionPlanRuntime = siddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(executionPlan);

StreamCallback streamCallback = new StreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void receive(Event[] events) {
        EventPrinter.print(events);
    }
};

executionPlanRuntime.addCallback("wso2Stream", streamCallback);
//Similarly, we can add another call back for abcStream

streamCallback.startProcessing();

InputHandler inputHandler = executionPlanRuntime.getInputHandler("cseEventStream");

executionPlanRuntime.start();

inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"WSO2", 700f, 100l});
inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"ABC", 60.5f, 200l});
inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"WSO2", 60.5f, 200l});

streamCallback.stopProcessing();
executionPlanRuntime.shutdown();
```

I've used Siddhi version 3.0.6-beta2.

This code sample is a modification made to one of the [Siddhi Passthrough test cases](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/release-3.0.6-beta2/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/PassThroughTestCase.java) (`PassThroughTest4`).

### Update:

Looking at [ExecutionPlanRuntime class](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/ExecutionPlanRuntime.java), it does not seem like it is possible to add queries "on the run".

So, to my understanding, you will have to shutdown current execution plan runtime, add those new queries and start it back.

Comment: Ok. But by adding I meant after the execution plan was created. After you started sending events, and while you are sending events.

Comment: Is there a way to do that for current version(4.3.0)?

Comment: @uğur-taş It is not possible to add queries "on the run" even on the [current version](https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi/releases/tag/v5.1.1). We would like to understand your requirement to do so. I'd suggest that you create an issue in [Siddhi git page](https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi/issues) so this can be discussed further.

Comment: I am adding rules according to options that is decided by users. Those options can be changed any time or user can add a new condition. Moreover conditions differ from user to user. That's why, I need to update it when a option change is happened.

Comment: @uğurtaş I have the same need as you and have had success just shutting down the `SiddhiAppRuntime` and starting it back up with the new queries. If you have complex queries (they need state from previous events) you can store a snapshot of the `SiddhiAppRuntime` before shutting it down then restore it once you start it back up with your new queries. I didn't see this recommended in the docs anywhere but I have tested it for myself and it seems to work well.

Comment: @wearebob I found another way to solve my problem. I have created a generic query that joins with a siddhi table. When a user adds, changes or removes a criteria table is also affected and in that way, siddhi query also affected and get changed.